# Calculate the percentage of a column base on year

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I want to get the percentage of column `Quantity` based on the same year.

| ID | Model | Year | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | M1 | 2020-01-01 | 10 |
| 2 | M2 | 2020-02-07 | 12 |
| 3 | M3 | 2020-11-20 | 7 |
| 4 | M1 | 2021-01-04 | 8 |
| 5 | M2 | 2021-05-19 | 5 |
| 6 | M3 | 2021-09-11 | 11 |
| 7 | M4 | 2021-10-26 | 3 |

I have tried the below code but I'm not getting the desired result. Kindly assist

```
SELECT 
    Model,
    DATEPART(yy, Year) AS Year,
    SUM(Qty) AS Quantity,
    ROUND (100 * SUM(Qty) / MAX( SUMALL), 2) AS Percentage
FROM 
    tblStore
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT SUM(Qty) SUMALL 
     FROM tblStore) A ON 1 = 1
GROUP BY 
    Model, Year
```

Expect output for my table should be like the one below

| ID | Model | Year | Qty | Percentage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | M1 | 2020-01-01 | 10 | 34.48 |
| 2 | M2 | 2020-02-07 | 12 | 41.38 |
| 3 | M3 | 2020-11-20 | 7 | 24.14 |
| 4 | M1 | 2021-01-04 | 8 | 29.63 |
| 5 | M2 | 2021-05-19 | 5 | 18.52 |
| 6 | M3 | 2021-09-11 | 11 | 40.74 |
| 7 | M4 | 2021-10-26 | 3 | 11.11 |

So if we add it manually we get in
2020 - 34.48 + 41.38 + 24.14 = 100% and       |
2021 - 29.63 + 18.52 + 40.74 + 11.11 = 100%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this mayhaps:

```sql
select  *
,   qty / (0.01 * SUM(qty) over(partition by year(year))) as percentage
from (
    VALUES  (1, N'M1', N'2020-01-01', 10)
    ,   (2, N'M2', N'2020-02-07', 12)
    ,   (3, N'M3', N'2020-11-20', 7)
    ,   (4, N'M1', N'2021-01-04', 8)
    ,   (5, N'M2', N'2021-05-19', 5)
    ,   (6, N'M3', N'2021-09-11', 11)
    ,   (7, N'M4', N'2021-10-26', 3)
) t (ID,Model,Year,Qty)
order by id
```

Returned data:

| ID | Model | Year | Qty | percentage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | M1 | 2020-01-01 | 10 | 34.48275862068965 |
| 2 | M2 | 2020-02-07 | 12 | 41.37931034482758 |
| 3 | M3 | 2020-11-20 | 7 | 24.13793103448275 |
| 4 | M1 | 2021-01-04 | 8 | 29.62962962962962 |
| 5 | M2 | 2021-05-19 | 5 | 18.51851851851851 |
| 6 | M3 | 2021-09-11 | 11 | 40.74074074074074 |
| 7 | M4 | 2021-10-26 | 3 | 11.11111111111111 |